# MVC3 - Display role name in viewbag.message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

In a ViewBag.Message, I would like to display the user's role in a message. If the user is of the "Client" role. I would like to add to the existing viewbag so it say's on the Home page Hello User123! You're a Client!

Comment: That's nice.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how do I display the rolename of the current user in the ViewBag?

Comment: You don't display anything in the ViewBag.  ViewBag is just a Dictionary that contains key/pair values.

Comment: I have done something similar with user First Name and Last Name where I spit back the user's first and last name in a message. I accomplish this in the viewbag. I would like to do the same for the user with the roles. I know it is possible but don't know exactly how to do it. I know it will be something similar to this: var profile = Profile.GetProfile(User.Identity.Name);
                ViewBag.Message = "HELLO " + profile.FirstName + " " + profile.LastName + "!";

Answer (score 1):

You can use the membership and role providers to get a collection of roles assigned to a user.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(); //Gets currently logged in user
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName); //Gets array of role names assigned to user
```

roles will be a string array because a user can be assigned to more than one role.  If you want to just use the first role, you could do this:

```
if( roles.Length > 0 )
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello Bob, you are a {0}", roles[0] ); 
}
```

In your view, you would access the Message property of the ViewBag to display your message.